# Using HttpContext.User ASP.NET Core MVC RC2 inside a service class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Looking at `ManageController` in a new project created with RC2 there is:

```
    private Task<ApplicationUser> GetCurrentUserAsync()
    {
        return _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
    }
```

I have tried to use it in class however its causing an error. The error is:

> The type or namespace name 'HtmlEncoder' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

In RC1 this worked however in RC2 its doesnt.

Right at the bottom of [this](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/migration/rc1-to-rc2.html) page on migration from RC1 RC2 it says:

> RC1 => HttpContext.User.GetUserId())  RC2 => UserManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);

Yet for me its not working.

How do I get the current logged in user using userManger?

Comment: "in class"? Which class? HttpContext is only available as property in controllers. If you want it in any other class that do not derive from `Controller` class, you need to inject `IHttpContextAccessor`

Comment: It was a service class - nothing fancy.  As suggested I used "_userManager.GetUserAsync(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User)" after injecting IHttpContextAccessor into the class. This worked.

Comment: Glad it worked. I posted the comment as answer. Next time just try to add as much information as possible, makes it easier then guessing ^^

Answer (score 1):

`HttpContext` as a property is only available inside controllers that derive from the `Controller` base class.

If you want it in any other class , you have to inject `IHttpContextAccessor`.